# How to see what Siri Shortcuts a user has created

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios12, sirishortcuts

I'm creating a Siri Shortcut and have inserted the "Add to Siri" button that one of the WWDC 2018 videos explains and demos. My question is if I can tell  when a user has created this specific shortcut which would leave the button useless or even a bug allowing the user to create multiple shortcuts for the same activity/intent.

Is there a way to access the list of shortcuts that the user has created from my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`INVoiceShortcutCenter getAllVoiceShortcuts`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/invoiceshortcutcenter/2963091-getallvoiceshortcuts)

Comment: how can you make sure that the VoiceShortcut is connected with one of the intents you are created??

Comment: There's another new function called [`INVoiceShortcutCenter getVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/invoiceshortcutcenter/2963092-getvoiceshortcutwithidentifier?language=objc) that might also be helpful for you @PatoSalazar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ThomasJoulin, I wrote this:

```
func getOldConnectShortcut(for activity: NSUserActivity, _ completion: @escaping ((INVoiceShortcut?) -> Void)) {
    INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts { shortcuts, err in
        guard err == nil, let shortcuts = shortcuts, !shortcuts.isEmpty
        else { completion(nil); return }
        for s in shortcuts{
            if s.shortcut.userActivity?.activityType == activity.activityType { completion(s); return }
        }
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Be aware that response comes in background Thread.